# base64 encode is giving ambigious results

Tags: command-line

I was encoding (from terminal) into base64. But I guess the commands are not executing properly.

```
$ echo 123456789 | base64
MTIzNDU2Nzg5Cg==
```

And then when I did the same on [base64encode](http://www.base64encode.org), I got this result

```
MTIzNDU2Nzg5
```

I thought that maybe `echo` is being encoded as well so i ran

```
$ echo | base64
Cg==
```

I guess i was right, but that didn't help either as in another instance:

```
$ echo qwertyuiop | base64
cXdlcnR5dWlvcAo=
```

and when the same was encoded using [base64encode](http://www.base64encode.org) the result was

```
cXdlcnR5dWlvcA==
```

And not suprisingly i the results from base64encode were accepted(in SMTP)

So, what am i missing here? and how can i sucessfully convert the string or number into base64?

Comment: **Hint:** what's the difference between `base64 -d <<< MTIzNDU2Nzg5` and `base64 -d <<< MTIzNDU2Nzg5Cg==`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The answer is simple. With

```
echo 123456789 | base64
```

or

```
echo qwertyuiop | base64
```

you always have a trailing newline.

---

Avoid this behavior by using the `n` switch for the `echo` command

```
% echo -n qwertyuiop | base64
cXdlcnR5dWlvcA==
```

or use `printf`

```
% printf qwertyuiop | base64
cXdlcnR5dWlvcA==
```

as you can see it is the same result as returned by [base64encode](https://www.base64encode.org/).

---

And as [@AndreaCorbellini](https://askubuntu.com/users/2979/andrea-corbellini) says in the comments

> Base64 produces 4 bytes of output for every 3 bytes of input, so there is never a 1:1 corrispondence between the input bytes and the output bytes. This means that a new line may end up being encoded in different ways, depending on the bytes that precede and follow it.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But when I did `echo | base64` I got `Cg==` as a result, but in `echo qwertyuiop | base64` is it `o=`? I got it that why was that happening, but I am still having a hard time understanding how this is happening.?

Comment: @Jarwin: base64 produces 4 bytes of output for every 3 bytes of input, so there is never a 1:1 corrispondence between the input bytes and the output bytes. This means that a new line may end up being encoded in different ways, depending on the bytes that precede and follow it.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Can I add your comment to the answer?

Comment: Of course======

Comment: If the answer is clear, you should accept by a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.